# PHPでDBのデータをCSVに出力したいが、CSVが生成されない

Tags: php, postgresql

開発初心者の質問で分かりにくい点が多々あるかと存じますが、ご了承くださいませ。

PHPファイル内で、postgreSQLを使いデータベース上のテーブルデータ全てをCSVファイルにしたいのですが、色々調べてはみたものの、解決できませんでした。
postgreSQLにお詳しい方、ご教示頂ければ幸いで御座います。

■phpコード（実行したファイル）

```
    <?php
    // PostgreSQLに接続
    $conn = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=test 
    user=XXXXX password=XXXXX');

    // 接続確認
    if( $conn ) {
    var_dump("接続に成功しました");
    } else {
    var_dump("接続できませんでした");
    }
    // SQL文を実行
    $query = "COPY test_json TO '/tmp/sampletbl1.csv' CSV";
    pg_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$query) {
      echo "An error occurred.\n";
      exit;
    }

    // PostgreSQLを切断
    $close = pg_close($conn);
    ?>
```

補足事項
・/tmp/sampletbl1.csv が作成されない状態です。
・MAMPを使用しております。
・DB接続は成功しております。
・PHPのエラーは発生致しておりません。
・PHPのバージョン：5.6.30
・PostgreSQLのバージョン：10.5
・MAMPのバージョン：5.0.1

データベースにつきまして
　ホスト名：localhost
　DB名:test
　取得したいテーブル名:test_json
　取得後のCSVファイル名：sampletbl1.csv

Comment: 確認ですが、`/tmp/sampletbl1.csv` が作成されないか、もしくは中身が空、という事でしょうか？

Comment: 説明が不足して申し訳ございません。/tmp/sampletbl1.csv が作成されない現状で御座います。

Comment: [マニュアル](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.pg-query.php)を参照しますと、`pg_query($conn, $query);` とした方が良さそうです。また、マニュアルに記載されているサンプルコードの様に pg_query() の戻り値を調べて、エラーメッセージを表示させる様にしてみると何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: ご教示頂き有難うござます。pg_query($conn, $query);へ変更し、エラーメッセージも追加いたしました。現状まだ現象はまだ解消されず、エラーメッセージは何も表示されないようでございます。引き続き調査致します！貴重な情報を教えて頂き有難うございました！

Comment: pg_queryの返り値の判定をしていないように見受けられますが、typoですかね？

Comment: ご確認頂き有難うござます。pg_queryの返り値の判定になにか不備等ございますでしょうか？ご教授頂けますと幸いで御座います。

Comment: `$a = pg_query($conn, $query);`として`$a`の中身を確認してみてください

Comment: $aの中身を確認致しました。resource(3) of type (pgsql result)と表示されるようで御座います。 こちらの件、明日また調査致します。本日は色々とご教示頂き有難うござました！大変勉強になりました

Comment: 結果リソースを判定する関数はリファレンスを参考にしてください。DBエラーはそれら関数を利用して自分で結果リソースを判定する必要があります。PHPエラーとしては吐き出されませんのでご注意を。

Comment: 承知致しました。リファレンスを参考に調査致します。ご指摘頂き有難うございます。

Comment: こちらの件、以下のパスの修正を行い、
無事にデータベースの情報がCSVファイルへ反映される事を確認致しました。
keitaro_so様忙しい中、ご教示頂き有りとうございました！また大変勉強になりました。

'/tmp/sampletbl1.csv' CSV";→'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tmp/sampletbl1.csv’;